# Strimzi kafka memory keeps increasing

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I setup Strimzi kafka in GKE., and configured dashboards for monitoring memory/cpu.
Noticed a behavior where in the memory graph is keep increasing from Grafana. Using container_memory_usage_bytes & container_memory_working_set_bytes metrics.,

[image]

I am suspecting this is will create a memory pressure at some point and will eventually get into OOM situation.

Can anybody suggest a solution for this please.?

Comment: Specifically what Docker image is this? Are those the brokers or Zookeeper or something else? You're looking at a range of less than 200MB, which is not a problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer. These are for the kafka brokers that are created through strimzi operator. Didnt get you when you are saying the range is less than 200mb., To be precise from my side, I have given the snippet of the spike. It all increase from 2GB gradually and increased till 5.18 GB. And we have a limit set of 6GB., which might create a OOM

Comment: Your shown plot y-axis is very small and within reasonable range of any Java application. If you've set the JVM max heap to be - Xmx6g, then you can expect memory to be less than that. Otherwise, if your brokers are idle and not doing anything, then you should tell us what version of Kafka they are, at the very least

Comment: @OneCricketeer., It Kafka 2.7 Version. Brokers are continuously running and messages are flowing flawlessly. Pod memory is configured to 6GB where in xmx is configured at 4G. We dont see any problem with JVM memory as such but the container memory is at the concern

Comment: You'd have to find someone that knows what the Strimzi container actually does, because if your Xmx is only 4G, then having over 1G usage above that for other processes seems like a lot

Answer (score 1):

Note that from Ubuntu 21+, DEbian 11, RH 9... cgroupv2 has been activated.
Currently, init shells in strimzi container images are relying on a /sys/fs/cgroup stat that does not exist anymore. This leads to no Xms/Xmx option computed, or badly computed.
This lead to OOM Kill of your various strimzi pods.

A strimzi bug has been raised on the subjec (https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-bridge/issues/731)

For the moment, you can patch this by providing jvmOptions settings in your 'Kafka' (cluster) Strimzi resource manifest in kafkaBridge, kafka, zookeeper, entityOprator.topicOperator sections

Also to be noted (but may be not your case here) : If your MEmory metric observes the overall Process+System usage of RAM, note that as kernel is using CACHE memory for disk IOs, it eventually reaches near 100% of usage, but cache memory is still available to be claimed by processes, so this is to be expected on any linux server running a disk-intensive application...